# Facebook-like chat for my Java web application

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, seam2, livechat

I am creating Facebook-like chat for my Java web application. But it does not work, I followed

below link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/cometd-facebook-similar-chat-for-your.html

Is there any other chat API available to create chat for my Java seam web app?

got an error on this function

on this function i got false in if condition

```
_metaHandshake: function (message) {
            // getting false :(
            if (message.successful) {
                $.cometChat._connectionInitialized();
            }
        },
```

help me if it is working with seam

Comment: have you considered using AJAX? https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/

Answer (score 0):

facebook uses a seperate XMPP server for handling the chat feature.
if you could try, use openfire xmppserver and strophejs javascript library.
you need to design your interface yourself and learn xmpp messages.

http://strophe.im/strophejs/

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/